# Mockk: How to mock a return after a delay?

Tags: kotlin, mocking, mockk

I need to mock a call to some class and make it take some time.

The current code uses  this:

```
every { useCase.execute(any()) } answers {
    AnswersWithDelay(50000, DoesNothing.doesNothing())
}
```

Now I am changing `execute()` to return an object of `Notification` class.

```
val notif = Notification(...)
```

But I can't figure out how to change this mock.

```
val answer: org.mockito.stubbing.Answer<Notification> = AdditionalAnswers.answer { invocation: InvocationOnMock -> notif }
val delayedAnswer = AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(50000, { invocation: InvocationOnMock -> answer } )
```

I can't find how to make the `answers { ... }` compilable. Any tips?

Answer (score 7):

The Mockito and MockK APIs are a bit confusing, because they share the terminology, but are not compatible. MockK's `io.mockk.Answer` is not compatible with Mockito's `org.mockito.stubbing.Answer`, and from there, all the other util classes do not match either.

So while originally it could have used `DoesNothing.doesNothing()`, because the return type was `Unit`/`void`, with a return type the mock must be created with MockK's idiomatic way.

So I resorted to:

```
    val answerF = FunctionAnswer { Thread.sleep(50000); notif }
    every { useCase.execute(any()) } .answers(answerF)
```